# Running socket.io behind nginx at a sublocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

I am trying to run an express-socket.io-angular.js Application on a raspberry my at my home.

Express and socket.io are running on port 3001. Accessing the Application at http://[IP]:3001 works fine. I would like to access the application at http://[IP]/ttt.

I configured nginx like this:

```
location /ttt/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
}
```

On the server i run these lines of code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

...

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

...

var io = require('socket.io')(http, {path: '/ttt/socket.io'});

...

http.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port 3001');
});
```

and at the client I include socket.io like this:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and connect like this:

```
socket: Socket = io.connect({path: "/ttt/socket.io"});
```

The problem:

I get all resources (html, css, js incl. socket.io.js), but in the browserlog i get error messages, that it was not able to get http://[IP]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LNGvDUd where t changes frequently.

It reports status 404, it's obvious, because nginx doesn't respond at /socket.io.

Thanks in advance!

---

Combined results with jfriend00:

The working setup looks like this:

nginx (found more details about the correct configuration [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/)):

```
location /ttt/ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    }
```

Express:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Client (Typescript):

```
socket: Socket = io({path: "/ttt/socket.io"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your proxy configuration correctly, it is going to strip off the `/ttt` from the path before forwarding on to port 3001.  As such, your socket.io initialization is not correct on the server.

Change this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {path: '/ttt/socket.io'});
```

to this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

EDIT:

And, make sure that your client file that's loading into the browser is actually  the latest edited client file.  You can check it with View/Source in the browser to see exactly what file you're running.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! Yes, you understood my proxy setup correctly.
I tried that, but the browser still tries to get /socket.io/... at the wrong URL

Comment: I don't know what this syntax in your client code means: `socket: Socket = io.connect({path: "/ttt/socket.io"});`.  It works for me with this in the client: `socket = io({path: "/ttt/socket.io"});` and `<script src="/ttt/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.

Comment: Sorry, but I still get the 404-Error on http://[IP]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LNGvDUd What part of the syntax do you mean?

Comment: @Stefan - Something is not as you show in the client because the `path` option to `io()` or `io.connect()` WILL change the URL the client requests there.  I've tried it myself.  It works.  What version of socket.io are you running?  Are you sure you don't have a socket.io connection somewhere else or that you're actually editing the proper client source file and that the old one is cached?l  You can do View/Source in the browser to see exactly which page it is running.

Comment: I found the error, my IDE was configured to auto-upload the files ON SAVE. After i compiled my ts-files it did not update the js files on the server.... Thank you very much for your help and telling me to check the files I got from the server :)

Comment: @Stefan - OK, I added that last bit to my answer so this answer covers both issues.